# a question about DATE_ADD

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to add 1 month and 3 months, should I do like that:

```
UPDATE `set` SET expire = DATE_ADD(`expire`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) WHERE ID='$lid'

UPDATE `set` SET expire = DATE_ADD(`expire`, INTERVAL 3 MONTHS) WHERE ID='$lid'
```

is that right ?

3 MONTH or 3 MONTHS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [it's always MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) - singular.

```
UPDATE `set` SET expire = DATE_ADD(`expire`, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) WHERE ID='$lid'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a safe way for you to try both syntaxes and see for yourself:

```
SELECT expire,DATE_ADD(expire,INTERVAL 3 MONTH) FROM set LIMIT 5;
SELECT expire,DATE_ADD(expire,INTERVAL 3 MONTHS) FROM set LIMIT 5;
```